# Using .split to split up content in a string

Tags: javascript, split

Hi I've got a string where I want to spilt up the content "ipsum dolar" and wrap it into a span tag and have the background change to red. My code does this but it wraps the two words into separate span tags. How would i amend my code to wrap them into one span tag together? Any help on this would be appreciated.

```js
var findWords = 'ipsum dolor';
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('p.content');

elem.forEach(function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = el.textContent.split(' ').map(function(i) {
    return findWords.indexOf(i) > -1 ? '<span class="matched">' + i + '</span>' : i;
  }).join(' ');
});
```

```css
.matched {background: red;}
```

```html
<p class="content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p class="content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: Maybe [this stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hk98oq?file=index.js) helps you along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) will be better in this case:

```js
var findWords = 'ipsum dolor';
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('p.content');

elem.forEach(function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = el.textContent.replace(new RegExp(findWords, 'g'), '<span class="matched">' + findWords + '</span>');
});
```

```css
.matched {background: red;}
```

```html
<p class="content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p class="content"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor</p>
```